# ASP.NET MVC - Google Maps Places AutoComplete not working inside Ajax returned form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps-api-3, google-places

I have added an google maps places library autocomplete plugin to an input control inside an ASP.NET MVC editor template. It is working fine when the template gets rendered normally. But it stops working inside forms that are returned via AJAX. The autocomplete initialization is being executed properly and I can even see the placeholder text on the input box but the autocomplete feature doesn't seem to run. Thanks in advance for any tips/suggestions in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. The issue was a higher value of z-index being used for a modal dialog that was hiding the autocomplete popup content. The z-index for the autocomplete popup is 1000.